# iPad / Mobile Safari: div fixed in one direction

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, jquery-mobile, safari

Allright stackxicans, how can I keep a div fixed in one direction only and move it with the scroll in the other direction in **Safari / iPad** ?

Yes, on desktop browsers, it's quite easy using javascript. But have you ever tried to do that on iPad ..check [this](http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/fixed-div.htm) for example. It's ugly. Numerous problems arise (to me, at least):

- the "scroll"-event is triggered only AFTER the scroll has finished,
- there are events like touchstart, touchmove, touchend - but if you try to use these to quickly calculate wheter it's a vertical or horizontal move and then set css-attributes, safari does not render your css-changes until the scroll is finished.

I always end up in unclean, laggy or ugly effects. The goal would be for the green header to only move horizontally and for the blue row to only move vertically on a scroll in the white content area.

[image: depiction]

Comment: Can you simplify the question?

Comment: Huangism, the core question is in the title: how to keep a div fixed e.g. on a vertical scroll, but move it on a horizontal scroll.

Comment: What is the nasty gimp effects? stuttering? or it doesn't work at all?

Comment: maybe you are thinking too much. You can most likely just have extra 2 elements on the page with the correct positioning css for each and just show/hide the correct ones on scroll left/right and up/down. You probably need to bind mousemove for ipad coords though

Comment: The effect is: if I move content to the right, the channellist (blue) behaves like absolute positioned and gets out of the visible area even though it is told to be fixed in touchmove/scroll-event and only then, after the scroll has finished, it moves to its - fixed - place.

Look at the link I gave in line 4 of my initial posting using IE/FF (does as wanted) and Safari (gimp).

Comment: And to your second comment... if I understand you right then this is no solution because it won't work synchronously/dynamically. There is no per-se right positioning, it depends on where in the content-div you have scrolled to.

Comment: I just viewed it on desktop safari and it seems fine

Comment: it's about the div in the top left corner that is supposed to stay fix on vertical scroll but relative on horizontal scroll. on ipad, it does not do that instantaniously. there is a delay: you scroll down - the div is hidden - the scroll is finished - the div is shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else is having a similar problem, here's my "solution". Disable

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

on your element of interest, then you can use sth. like

```
var element = $("#element");
element.bind('touchmove', function (e) {
    scrollTop = element.scrollTop();
    scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft();
    $(".yAxisHeader").css({ left: 0, top: -scrollTop });
    $(".xAxisHeader").css({ top: 0, left: -scrollLeft });
});
```

as know from desktop browser solutions. Trade-off: the nice smooth-scrolling-inertia effect is lost.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll event is slightly dodgy on a mobile device as in effect it renders the entire page and just moves it around the screen, it's not scrolling as we'd expect it which is why we struggle to use fixed or sticky positions in CSS.

Rather than attaching to the scroll event I'd find an alternative and check on the position of the document.

http://cubiq.org/iscroll is a good plugin to help